# If i update wordpress would i lose my custom made theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am looking to develop my own wordpress theme. If there is an wordpress update, would I lose my theme and its changes?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely not.  Wordpress updates won't touch anything in the theme directory, assuming you've built a custom theme.  If you are just modifying one of the default themes directly (e.g. TwentyFourteen) it might get updated if you also update the themes.  In that case you'd want to be using a child theme.

But from your question it sounds like you're talking about a custom theme, so it will not get overwritten.

Here's more information on wordpress updates: http://codex.wordpress.org/Updating_WordPress